# Iterator that jumps forward and backward. Borrowing mutably more than once

Tags: rust

I'm writing a virtual machine that executes instructions one by one and also can jump forward and backward.

For example, if it has a list of instructions `[A, >B, C, D]` and currently is at instruction `B`. Jumping forward by 2 will skip 2 instructions (`B` and `C`) `[A, B, C, >D]`. And jumping back by 1 should skip only `B` `[>A, B, C, D]`.

This is how I implemented the iterator

```rust
impl <'a> Iterator for VmReader<'a> {
    type Item = &'a Instruction;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.ip < self.chunk.code.len() {
            let instruction: &'a Instruction = &self.chunk.code[self.ip];
            self.ip += 1;
            Some(instruction)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

The `reader` stores the index of the current instruction and `jump_backward(2)` decrements it by 2.

Here's how I'm trying to use it:

```rs
while let Some(instruction) = reader.next() {
    if instruction == &Instruction::Add {
        reader.jump_backward(2);
        continue;
    }
}
```

But it does not work since I'm borrowing `reader` mutably twice:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `reader` as mutable more than once at a time
   --> src/vmm/vm_reader.rs:99:39
    |
99  |         while let Some(instruction) = reader.next() {
    |                                       ^^^^^^
    |                                       |
    |                                       second mutable borrow occurs here
    |                                       first borrow later used here
100 |             if instruction == &Instruction::Add {
101 |                 reader.jump_backward(2);
    |                 ------ first mutable borrow occurs here
```

Can you please suggest a solution to this problem?

Comment: Will move the comment to your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be to not use the `Iterator` trait but using an iterator like structure which would wrap the `ip` cursor but not the reader and whose `next` function would take the reader as argument.

It would look somehow like this:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct VmIterator {
     ip: usize,
}
impl VmIterator {
    pub fn next(&mut self, chunk: &Reader) -> Option<&Instruction> {
        if self.ip < chunk.code.len() {
            let instruction: &'a Instruction = &self.chunk.code[self.ip];
            self.ip += 1;
            Some(instruction)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

This would be safe and clean but would prevent some Iterator patterns.

---

If you don't need to separate the Reader and the iteration, you may also store directly the ip cursor in the Reader.

Here's an example of this second solution:

```
#[derive(Debug, Default, Clone)]
struct Instruction {}

struct Reader<'s> {
    source: &'s[Instruction],
    c: usize,
}

impl<'s> Reader<'s> {
    pub fn new(source: &'s[Instruction]) -> Self {
        Self { source, c: 0 }
    }
    pub fn decr(&mut self) {
        self.c -= 2;
    }
}

impl<'s> Iterator for Reader<'s> {
    type Item = &'s Instruction;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let c = self.c;
        if c < self.source.len() {
            self.c += 1;
            self.source.get(c)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let instructions = vec![Instruction::default(); 10];
    let mut r = Reader::new(&instructions);
    let mut i = 0;
    while let Some(c) = r.next() {
        if i%3 == 2 {
            r.decr();   
        }
        i += 1;
        dbg!(c);
    }
}
```

Note that while it's still an iterator, some Iterator constructs will be forbidden by the borrow checker if you mutate while iterating, hence the explicit `while let Some(c) = r.next() {`.

Comment: Thanks! But if we are abandoning the iterator pattern, then can it be implemented without the iterator at all while encapsulating the `ip` field? I'm asking it because this solutions spawn 2 entities: `Reader` and `Iterator` which seems cumbersome :)

Comment: The new "Iterator" is just the ip field, doesn't take more place in memory than a usize, it's just added type security.

Comment: Okay, I'm just asking not in terms of performance and optimization but in terms of software architecture, because now the code base will have 2 entities. Do you think it can be done with 1 entity?

Comment: Depends on your use cases but there's no problem storing a `reading_index` inside the original structure if there's only one possible reading. In the general case, separating the data and the iteration is a little more flexible, though.

Comment: But will I be able to mutate that `reading_index` inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, here's an example: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd809ffb261e7de0714496329a95f5bc (edited)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231361/discussion-between-furetur-and-denys-seguret).